# Research in realtime computational physics?

Tags: graphics, mathematical-programming, physics

I am aware that there is a considerable amount of interest in computational mechanics for simulation of cloth, hair and other elastica, particularly for animation films. The methods developed by groups in computational mechanics (that I am aware of) are typically far from real time.

My question is if there are any departments or people specialising in real time simulation of computational physics, with potential application to computer games, realtime virtual worlds, or educational tools? I am specifically interested in research groups in the University setting.

Comment: http://physbam.stanford.edu/~fedkiw/

Comment: 1. We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a 
[general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). 
Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and
[this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; 
you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems 
explained there.  2. Also, I'm not sure whether your question is on-topic here, as it is not a technical question about computer science.  Community voters, do we want non-technical questions about who is working in a particular research area?

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com may be a better place to ask a question like this